# Tests of hash collision on ASCII characters

Tags: c++, caching, hash, collision

I'm currently in the process of building a caching system for some of our back end systems, which means that I'll need a hash table of some sort, to represent cached entities. In this context, I was wondering if anyone knows about any tests showing different algorithms and the minimum ASCII string length necessary to provoke a collision? Ie. what's a safe length (ASCII characters) to hash with a range of functions?

The reason is of course that I want the best trade off between size (the cache is going to be representing several million entities on relatively small servers), performance and collision safety.

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a strong hash, I'd suggest something like the [Jenkins Hash](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/perfect.html). This should be less likely to generate clashes. In terms of algorithms, what you're looking for is an [avalanche test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect)
[Bob Jenkins' Site](http://burtleburtle.net/bob) has a whole lot of handy information on this sort of thing.
As for the size of the hash table, I believe Knuth recommends having it large enough so that with a perfect hash, 2/3 of the table would be full, while Jenkins recommends the nearest greater power of two

Hope this helps!